# Macos Finder / Terminal Weirdness

Tags: macos, terminal, finder

Working on my 'elder' iMac (High Sierra) I noticed that a directory I have been working in shows me files that are there. But in Terminal, viewing the same directory, I see files that should have been just deleted.
The directory I'm working in is where I am converting .flac files to .mp3 with ffmpeg via a Perl script.
Once converted, I delete the files via the Perl script.
So why is there a difference between what Finder shows me and what Terminal shows me?

Results of ls -l /Volumes

```
~/Desktop/Colourbox - Disc 4 (2012) [user] ls -l /Volumes
total 8
drwxrwxr-x  25 user  admin   918 Jul 31 11:24 Backup3
lrwxr-xr-x   1 root  wheel     1 Sep  8 10:14 Macintosh HD -> /
drwxrwxr-x  13 root  wheel   510 Sep  8 11:16 Nano
drwxrwxrwx  33 user  wheel  1360 Sep  3 18:00 echo1
drwxrwxr-x+ 18 root  wheel   952 Jun 27 09:07 femto
drwxrwxr-x   9 user  wheel   544 Jul 30 17:02 ssd1
2021-09-08 11:43:44
~/Desktop/Colourbox - Disc 4 (2012) [user]
```

Screen shots:
[image: Image of ls]

[image: Image of Finder]

Relevant code is a couple of subroutines in a large script so will have to pull out only the code applicable.

Comment: Have you considered the possibility that you’re actually looking at two different directories? What does `pwd` tell you? What path do you see when you drag the folder from Finder into a Terminal window?

Comment: Yes, that was something I considered as it would be easy to do. I have double-checked and mailed screenshots to several friends including the path. None came back with that consideration.

Comment: Can you share your screenshots? Along with the script.

Comment: /Users/user/Desktop/Screen Shot 2021-09-06 at 6.50.55 PM.png
/Users/user/Desktop/Screen Shot 2021-09-06 at 6.50.32 PM.png
Not sure if these 2 images were included.

Comment: You need to edit your question and add the images there

Comment: Ctrl-G did not work so I will have to u/l them and provide links.

Comment: <https://www.softouch.on.ca/scratch/Screen%20Shot%202021-09-06%20at%206.50.55%20PM.png>
<https://www.softouch.on.ca/scratch/Screen%20Shot%202021-09-06%20at%206.50.32%20PM.png>

Comment: Can you edit your question (not add a comment) with those links and also the output of `ls -la /Volumes`?

Comment: And, also, please paste the relevant section(s) of the script which create and delete files.

Comment: Can you try dragging `1.mp3` into a Terminal window and sharing the resulting path here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It may be that my eyes are playing tricks on me, but it almost looks like in Finder you've navigated into a subdirectory of `M-Sol Project` whereas in Terminal you've navigated to a subdirectory of `M–Sol Project`. If these look identical to you, it's because I used an **en dash** (<kbd>-</kbd>) in the former and an **em dash** (<kbd>Option</kbd><kbd>-</kbd>) in the latter. One is very slightly wider than the other, but they are two distinct characters and would result in two different folder paths.

Can you navigate to `/Volumes/ssd1/httpd/public/local/music/data/` and see what `ls -l` gives you?

Comment: If that turns out to be true, what a good eye!

Comment: Wow that catches me more often than anything else. I try to use copy-paste to avoid that, and do the encoding along the way.
Thank you very much for catching that and pointing it out eh!